# How to use Perl chmod to add Set Group ID on a directory?

Tags: linux, perl, chmod

I can use the Perl `chmod` function to set the permission bits, for example:

```
chmod S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IROTH, $the_dir;
```

How do I add Set Group ID to the directory in the above command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know what the `S_xxx` alias is for the set group id bit, but it's value is (octal) 02000. So one of

```
chmod 02000|S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IROTH, $the_dir;

chmod 02774, $the_dir;
```

will probably work.

**Edit:** Now I do know what the appropriate `S_xxx` constant is named: it's `S_ISGID`.

```
$ perl -MFcntl -e 'printf "0%o", Fcntl::S_ISGID()'
02000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `chmod` to do that. Use `chown` and set the uid to -1, i.e.

```
chown -1, $groupid, $the_dir;
```